# Filling a ComboBox with LINQ on Silverlight (WPF)

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, combobox

Im trying to load a XML into an object with LinQ in Silverlight with WPF, but i can't fill or binding my combobox.

The code of the object is:

```
    public class Language_Index
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My XML is:

```
<languages_index>
<item prefix="VBNET" name="Visual Basic .NET" status="enabled" />
<item prefix="CS" name="C#" status="disabled" />
```

and the Code to load and present data is:

```
            string XmlString = e.Result; // Got all your XML data in to a string 

        XDocument elem = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XmlString)));

        var feed_language_index = from nod in elem.Descendants("languages_index")
                                  select new Language_Index
                                  {
                                      Name = nod.Element("item").Attribute("name").Value,
                                      Status = nod.Element("item").Attribute("status").Value,
                                      Prefix = nod.Element("item").Attribute("prefix").Value

                                  };

        LanguageSelector.ItemsSource = feed_language_index;
```

Of course the pasted code has no errors, but doesnt work.
LanguageSelector its my combo. There is NO problem in the linq, the problem is when i binding the combobox :)

That i really want is try to do something like:
MyComboBox.DataSource = MyClass.name;
for every element.

thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try converting your LINQ to a list and check your VS output window for binding errors.

```
    string XmlString = e.Result;

    XDocument elem = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XmlString)));

    var feedLanguages = 
            (from nod in elem.Descendants("languages_index")
            select new Language_Index
            {
                    Name = nod.Element("item").Attribute("name").Value,
                    Status = nod.Element("item").Attribute("status").Value,
                    Prefix = nod.Element("item").Attribute("prefix").Value
            }).ToList();

    LanguageSelector.ItemsSource = feedLanguages;
```

Sorry for removing your underscores. :)

Comment: thanks for corrected code! And what happens if i wanna an instance of "Language_Index" filled with the select of the linq and then try to load the combobox (languageselector) with that instance of language_index? :)

Comment: Sorry, i tried the code but it doesnt work. Maybe i need to specify something at XAML? thanks

Comment: Obiously you need to specify an ItemTemplate to show these things there. eg.
<ComboBox><ComboBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><StackPanel><TextBlock Text={Binding Name}/><TextBlock Text={Binding Status }/><TextBlock Text={Binding Prefix}/></StackPanel></DataTemplate></ComboBox.ItemTemplate></ComboBox>

Comment: No worries. I recommend WPF Unleashed by Adam Nathan - very strong learning foundation to WPF and useful for Silverlight too.